# Can we burninate [submodule]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

Here's some info on the [submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/submodule) tag:

- It [currently has no wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/submodule/info).
- It currently has 260 questions tagged.
- Of those 260 questions, [about 206 of them](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/211028/posts-tagged-with-both-submodule-and-git) are also tagged with [git].
- The remaining 55 [are mostly unrelated to Git](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/211034/questions-tagged-with-submodule-but-not-git):

  ```
    <arrays><module><vhdl><submodule>
    <codeigniter><submodule><hmvc>
    <content-management-system><heroku><submodule>
    <cython><importerror><setup.py><submodule>
    <dependencies><maven><profile><submodule>
    <django><deployment><heroku><submodule><pythonpath>
    <django><django-south><submodule>
    <django><module><submodule>
    <eclipse><playframework-2.1><submodule>
    <events><module><yii><submodule>
    <excel><vba><excel-vba><macros><submodule>
    <github><git-submodules><submodule>
    <github><jenkins><submodule>
    <github><submodule>
    <github><submodule>
    <git-submodules><git-merge><submodule><git-pull><git-commit>
    <inheritance><maven><dependencies><pom.xml><submodule>
    <internationalization><module><yii><submodule>
    <ios><dependencies><duplicates><static-libraries><submodule>
    <iphone><objective-c><xcode><static-libraries><submodule>
    <java><eclipse><svn><maven><submodule>
    <javascript><html><gruntjs><submodule>
    <javascript><node.js><dependency-injection><dependency-management><submodule>
    <javascript><submodule><javascript-namespaces>
    <maven><dependencies><versioning><submodule>
    <maven><maven-plugin><pom.xml><submodule>
    <maven><submodule><multi-module>
    <perforce><submodule>
    <perl><oop><perl-module><submodule>
    <php><submodule>
    <python><class><module><submodule>
    <python><django><django-celery><submodule>
    <python><documentation><package><python-sphinx><submodule>
    <python><function><module><submodule>
    <python><import><module><submodule>
    <python><import><module><submodule>
    <python><import><module><submodule>
    <python><import><module><submodule>
    <python><import><module><submodule>
    <python><import><module><submodule>
    <python><import><package><submodule>
    <python><import><submodule>
    <python><import><submodule>
    <python><module><finder><submodule>
    <python><module><import><traversal><submodule>
    <python><module><package><submodule>
    <python><module><packages><submodule>
    <python><module><parent><submodule>
    <python><python-3.x><import><submodule>
    <python><submodule><python-import>
    <ruby-on-rails><capistrano><submodule>
    <ruby-on-rails><rspec><models><submodule>
    <submodule>
    <svn><plugins><submodule>
    <xcode><submodule>
  ```

### Can we BURNINATE this tag please?

So as I've shown above, [submodule] is mostly used with Git. Except that's unnecessary, because [Git already has a [git-submodule] tag with 753 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-submodules?sort=newest&pageSize=50). Additionally, the tag is being used for questions that also involve "modules", but aren't at all related to Git.

#### Issues

The only issue that I can think of with the burnination is that [there are 206 questions tagged with [git] and [submodule], but aren't tagged with [git-submodule]](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/211046/tagged-with-submodule-and-git-but-not-git-submodule). Burninating [submodule] will leave those questions with only the [git] tag, unless moderators have special tools to retag these with [git-submodule] instead.

The same issue applies somewhat to questions that aren't tagged with [git], *but who cares about those*, #AmIRite? <sub>That was a joke.</sub>

What do people think?

Comment: I suggest removing it from the questions that are not also tagged [git], and synonymizing it to [git-submodule].

Comment: @RobertHarvey What happens to questions that are already tagged [git-submodule] when the synonym is created? Does the system remove the now essentially "duplicated" tags?

Comment: @Joe: Only if I merge.

Comment: @RobertHarvey good suggestion, I was thinking that might be a good solution for this.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I've removed the tag from the questions that aren't also tagged with Git, can submodule be made a synonym for git-submodules now, or should I make a new synonym request?